# How to sync TabRow indicator with HorizontalPager scroll offset?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

Accompanist has https://google.github.io/accompanist/api/pager-indicators/com.google.accompanist.pager/pager-tab-indicator-offset.html

Without it, the indicator just jumps to end positions, doesn't mirror the scroll offset "per pixel"

Is this or equivalent available in 1st party? (TabRow & HorizontalPager are now 1st party composables)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Migration guide](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#migration-table) there's no 1st party equivalent:

> Implement it yourself, or still include and use `accompanist-pager-indicators`, it now supports `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerState`

You still can use Accompanist variant using dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:$accompanistVersion"
```

Or copy source from the library.